# How to select destination output device using Web Audio API

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I  have been using web audio API and have created a context, and populated a source buffer with data. It plays fine over the default output device, but I don't understand how to choose the destination. In an old w3 spec you were able to pass in the correct `deviceId` to the audio context constructor, but I can't figure out how to do it now without using a media element. Any suggestions?

```
source = context.createBufferSource()
source.loop = true;
source.buffer = globalAudioBuffer;
source.connect(context.destination);
context.resume();
source.start(0);
```

Comment: 1/2 Are there nowadays a way to select the audio output device for a HTML page using WebAudioAPI, supported in the latest stable Chrome or latest stable Firefox? Maybe using Audio Output Devices API? A simple runnable example would be interesting for many purposes.

Comment: 2/2 Let's say I want the browser audio output to go to ASIO4ALL (to benefit from very low latency - for a in-browser musical sampler I'm currently building), how to do this in Chrome or Firefox for Windows?

Comment: PS: in the case of Chrome or Firefox for Windows

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting the destination audio device of a webaudio graph isn't yet implemented, and the api for this is not yet finalized.

What you can do for now, is connect the webaudio graph to an HTML element, and [set the sinkid of the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId) (currently works on Chrome only)

Here is a simple example:

```
var ac = new AudioContext();
var audio = new Audio();
var o = ac.createOscillator();
o.start();
var dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
o.connect(dest);
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(dest.stream);
audio.play();
```

Now your oscillator will play through the audio element and
you can now call `audio.setSinkId()` with the deviceId of a connected output device.

Comment: Thank you. I may try your workaround when i get back to that project or i may just wait for the Audio Output devices api to mature.

Comment: Good luck. If you want to know the status of this feature you can follow the [open issue](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/445#issuecomment-289768963).

Comment: Tried this again and got it. mediaDevices.getUserMedia will give you your deviceIDs and labels which will allow you to set a defined mediaStreamDestination. Then you just source.connect(dest). I don't even understand why we need a dedicated audio output api now?

Comment: @Rogue45 I don't understand your question. In a regular Web Audio case, we will simply connect the source to the audioContext destination. In your case, since you want to specify what audio device to use, you need to create a mediaStreamDestination and route it to an audio output element. This is kind of a hack, as we are mixing to unrelated APIs. Also, the audio output API is not meant to be used for user generated audio. It ais usually used to simply stream audio files or audio urls

Comment: Strangely, this approach is causing audio glitching for us with heavy main thread load (e.g. lots of oscillators started in a short period of time), and a *detuned audio output (!)* for a few seconds afterwards, observable from chrome 56 all the way to 63 (current). My assumption is that main thread load interferes either with the `MediaStream` object, or the `HTMLAudioElement`. Any experience with this?

Comment: @JohnWeisz Could you be experiencing these issues?
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595635#c1 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766198

Comment: @Asher Those definitely look the same, although I'm unable to reproduce the problem in *those* issues, the sound comes out all OK. I'm seeing past commitment, so perhaps *some* cases were fixed, others left in the dark.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Here is a more updated Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766198

Comment: @Asher I think you can omit the creation of an ObjectUrl. As the `audio.srcObject` takes in a stream, you can adapt the second to last line by: `audio.srcObject = dest.stream;`
Everything else should work fine, but you won't have a memory leak if you don't revoke your created ObjectURL.

Comment: The latest issue WRT the audio glitching in Chromium is here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1157478

Answer (score 1):

Complete example that works in Chrome 100, but not in Firefox 98.

Posting this here since the other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069474/1005419 doesn't work here (the call to `createObjectURL` is invalid) and because the other answer doesn't show the `setSinkId()` usage.

The snippet below plays the audio on the 3rd audio output device found on the system (`audioDevices[2]`).

Try it out at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq2wjc76/3/).

```js
async function playAudio() {
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: { deviceId: undefined },
    video: false
  });
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  const audioDevices = devices.filter((device) => {
    return (
      device.kind === "audiooutput"
    );
  });
  const audioDevice = audioDevices[2];

  var audioContext = new AudioContext();
  var audioElement = new Audio();
  await audioElement.setSinkId(audioDevice.deviceId);
  var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  var mediaStreamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
  oscillator.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
  audioElement.srcObject = mediaStreamDestination.stream;

  oscillator.start();
  audioElement.play();
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  oscillator.stop();
}

playAudio();
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome provides an experimental API since v 110.0 to select output device.
`AudioContext.setSinkId(id: string)` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/setSinkId))

To obtain the deviceId, you can enumerate devices with `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`.

```js
// build your graph
const context = new AudioContext()
source = context.createBufferSource()
source.loop = true;
source.buffer = globalAudioBuffer;
source.connect(context.destination);
context.resume();
source.start(0);

const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
const outputDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'audiooutput' && device.deviceId !== 'default');

// Select a new device
const selectedDevice = outputDevices[1]

await context.setSinkId(selectedDevice.deviceId)
```

Alternativaley, you can provide your deviceId as an option when you instantiate your audioContext ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext#browser_compatibility)).

```js
// build your graph
const context = new AudioContext({sinkId: "bb04fea9a8318c96de0bd..."})
[...]
```

Limitations:

- Currently implemented only on Chrome >v110, but Firefox ([position](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/683)) and Safari ([position](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/53)) are working on it (or seems to be ok to work on it)
- Chrome Web Audio API implementation returns incorrect `maxChannelCount` property. This means that if you want to change your output device for a multichannel output device, there is a good chance that `maxChannelCount` be still 2.